# Why can we say that if $d$ divides both $a$ and $b$, then it also divides the remainder of $a/b$?

Tags: divisibility

Why can we say that if $d$ divides both $a$ and $b$, then it also divides the remainder of $a/b$?

For example if $a=121$ and $b=44$, then we could say that $d=11$. The remainder of $121/44$ is $33$, and this is also divisible by $11$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Division Algorithm, we can write $a=bq+r$ for unique integers $q$ and $r$. In this case, $r$ is called the *remainder*.

Now, if $d$ divides $a$ and $b$, it also divides any linear combination of these, in particular
$$d\mid a-bq =r$$

Comment: $r$ is unique under the constraint $0 ≤ r < b$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\,a\bmod b\,$ arises by (repeatedly) ${\rm\color{#c00}{subtracting}}\ b$ from $a,\,$ but [multiples of $d$ are closed under $\rm\color{#c00}{subtraction}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2942475/242).

**Remark** $ $ If you are familiar with groups or ideals you should find it instructive to view this from that more abstract viewpoint. Sets of (common) multiples are propotypical examples of ideals, being closed under subtraction and scaling (or, equivalently, under linear combinations).