# If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $\gcd\left(a, (b^{-1}\ \rm{mod}\ a)\right)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I was looking for proof of the two problems like this.

The first one is if $$\gcd(a, b) = 1$$ then $$\gcd\left(a, (b^{-1}\ \rm{mod}\ a)\right)=1$$
which $(b^{-1}\ \rm{mod}\ a)$ is the modular multiplicative inverse of $b$ in $\rm{mod}\ a$ .

And the second one is if
$$\gcd(a, b_n) = 1\ \text{ and }\  b_n = sb_i\ \text{ and }\ B = b_n\times(b_n^{-1}\ \rm{mod}\ a)$$
then
$$\gcd(b_i, \frac{B-1}{a})=1$$

In order to proof this problems I did like this
$$A=(b^{-1} \mod\, a)$$
$$bk \equiv 1 \mod a$$
$$k \equiv A \mod a$$
so
$$k=ak_1+A $$
now
if $A=ak_2$

then
$$k=ak_1+ak_2=a(k_1+k_2)=ak_3$$
but
$$k=ak_1+A$$
as $$A\neq 0$$
so it's a contradiction as a result
$$A\neq ak_1$$
$$\gcd\left(a, A\right)=1$$
$$\gcd\left(a, (b^{-1}\ \rm{mod}\ a)\right)=1$$

for the second one I did like this:
$$B=b_nA = b_i\times sA = b_i k$$
so
$$\frac{B-1}{a}=\frac{b_i k-1}{a}=D$$
now if $D=b_ik_0 \text{  for  } k_0 \in Z$
$$\frac{b_i k-1}{a}=b_ik_0$$
$$\frac{b_i k-1}{ab_i}=k_0=\frac{k-1}{ab_i}-\frac{1}{ab_i}$$
so $$k_0 \notin Z$$
but we said that  $k_0 \in Z $
and this one is contradiction too so
$$D\neq b_ik_0$$
so
$$gcd(D,b_i)=1$$

but I'm not sure if it is true or not!!

Comment: Please tell us how do you think about these problems and include your efforts in the post.

Comment: thanks for review , I edited the post  and it's now include my proofs.@on1921379

Comment: thanks I fixed it .@PeterPhipps

Comment: These are *immediate* consequences of the basic divisibility properties that are proved in the linked dupes. Let $\,b' = b^{-1} \bmod a,\,$ so $\,bb'\equiv 1\pmod{a}\Rightarrow \color{#c00}b\color{#0a0}{b'}+\color{#0a0}a\color{#c00}n = 1.\,$ [Thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2942475/242) $\,\color{#0a0}{(a,b')}=1,\,$ and $\, 1 =\color{#c00}{(b,n)} = (b,(bb'\!-\!1)/a) = (b,B\!-\!1)/a),\,$ [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3555122/242) $\,b_i\mid b \Rightarrow (b_i,B\!-\!1)/a)=1$

Answer (score -1):

The proof of the first problem is as follows. $\gcd(a,b)=1$, so $$\gcd(a,(b^{-1}\mod a))=\gcd(a,b\cdot(b^{-1}\mod a))=\gcd(a,(1\mod a))=1.$$